# Tiered Pricing for Total Units Sold

Tags: price

I'm sure there is a solution but I just can't find it in because I'm not sure what to ask in google.

Is there a a way to have tiered pricing based on the total units sold in the deal?

For example I have a machine that anyone can buy. But the more people that buy the lower the price gets for everybody. It doesn't have to be a friend just as long as 10 other people buy the new price will kick in.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If this means, the price is decreased for *ALL* especially the ones which already bought it, is is "impossible". You are not allowed to change an order afterwards, because this will kill your accounting.

If you ignore this fact and only reduces the price for the new orders, you could implement an observer, which reduces the price, unit by unit.

The problem is, magento doesn't allow easy and just-in-time calculation of unit solded. This is part of the reporting and is only updated once a day or when you click the button in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're saying. Perhaps I should explain the model. We're using this as an internal purchasing platform for a group of 300 businesses that are a part of our association.

Let's say I have a machine that is $1000 but if 10 people in the association buy it it will be reduced to $900.

People are able to "hold" a unit by paying $50 and the more people who "hold" the lower the end price will be when purchases are put through at the end of the deal period.

Does that make any sense?

David